# Getting Microsoft Team context in an "Content page" added as a tab

Tags: javascript, microsoft-teams

I have created simple ".aspx" content page, and added this page as a Tab in "Microsoft Teams". I want to get the "SharePoint Url" of Microsoft Team where content page added as Tab. To do this I need "microsoftteams.context" object. Please let me know how to resolve this problem. I tried below code (with microsoft teams JS library) but its not working.

```
microsoftTeams.initialize();
microsoftTeams.getContext(function(Context) {
 alert("getcontext call back function");
 alert(Context.teamName);
});

microsoftTeams.initialize();
microsoftTeams.getContext(function(Context) {
 alert("getcontext call back function");
 alert(Context.teamName);
});
```

Comment: Do you want teams sharepoint url or tabs url where sharepoint content page is added ?

Comment: SharePoint URL.

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample code to fetch teamSiteUrl.

```
<p>
    Welcome to Microsoft Teams Hello World sample app (C#)
</p>
<script src="https://statics.teams.microsoft.com/sdk/v1.4.2/js/MicrosoftTeams.min.js"></script>
<script>
    microsoftTeams.initialize();
    microsoftTeams.getContext(function (context) {
        alert(context.teamSiteUrl);
        //teamSiteUrl will give you sharepoint url of the team.
    });
</script>
```

Please give it a try and let us know if you are facing any issue.

Comment: I already tried this it doesn't work. Please find screenshot, after code executes it just shows "undefined", and there is no alert.I have tried this code in developer tool of Microsoft teams.

Comment: I know how to get SharePointURL, once teams context object is present. But I am not able to get teams context.

Comment: Could you please share your content page code Or URL which we can access and check?

Comment: <asp:Content ID="PageWithMegaMenu" ContentPlaceHolderID="Child1_1Level2ContentPH" runat="server">    
    
    <script src="../Scripts/CampusMicrosoftTeams.js?rev=3"></script>

    <div class="container-fluid">        
    </div>
        
    <script>
        microsoftTeams.initialize();
        microsoftTeams.getContext(function (context) {
            var url = context.teamSiteUrl;
        });
    </script>
    
</asp:Content>

Comment: I have downloaded "Microsoft Teams" library code in my local, and referring from that location.

Comment: Thanks for providing code will try your code and let you know.

Comment: We tried you code and able to get the teamSiteUrl, please try with latest JavaScript sdk for Microsoft Teams here is the link [MicrosoftTeams](https://statics.teams.microsoft.com/sdk/v1.4.2/js/MicrosoftTeams.min.js)